# Document Library add file with custom column (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: document-library, column, document

I have a document library with a custom column. I want to add a file programatically, as well as a value for the custom column(lookup column).

```
 
SPFile file = sourceListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(sourceListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
                byte[] imageData = file.OpenBinary();
                SPFile newFile = files.Add(destinatioList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name, imageData, true);
                Hashtable targetItem = newFile.Item.Properties;
                //SPListItem targetItem = destinatioList.AddItem();
                targetItem["Venue Name"] = sourceListItem["Venu Name"].ToString();
                newFile.Update();
```

It does add the file to the document library, but it does not add the value for the custom column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make sure the column names are correct for Target and Source? Plus also try using Internal names of the columns, i.e. `Venue_x0020_Name` instead of `Venue Name` and `Venu_x0020_Name` instead of `Venu Name`

Answer (score 1):

i have two list
-custom list (Venues)(has an attachment file )
- pic library (Venue Gallery)(has lookup field)
i try to enter the attachment with the field name (venu name) in the pic library

```
base.ItemAdded(properties);
            SPListItem sourceListItem = properties.ListItem;
            SPDocumentLibrary destinatioList = (SPDocumentLibrary)sourceListItem.Web.Lists["Venue Gallery"];
            SPFileCollection files = destinatioList.RootFolder.Files;
foreach (string fileName in sourceListItem.Attachments)
            {
                SPFile file = sourceListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(sourceListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
                byte[] imageData = file.OpenBinary();
                SPFile newFile = files.Add(destinatioList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name, imageData, true);
                SPListItem targetItem = newFile.Item;
                //Hashtable targetItem = newFile.Item.Properties;
                //SPListItem targetItem = destinatioList.AddItem();
                targetItem["Venue_x0020_Name"] = sourceListItem["Venu_x0020_Name"].ToString();
                targetItem.Update();
```

`}
        destinatioList.Update();`

this is my code 
the sourceListItem is correct but i cant find the target property to but the text on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set metadata on the item directly and then update the item, not the file.  Try this:

```
SPFile file = sourceListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(sourceListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
byte[] imageData = file.OpenBinary();
SPFile newFile = files.Add(destinatioList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name, imageData, true);
SPListItem targetItem = newFile.Item;
targetItem["Venue Name"] = sourceListItem["Venu Name"].ToString();
targetItem.Update();
```

Comment: still not work 
when i make attache processes in target item i cant find my new field

Comment: I guess I need better context on how/where you are using this code, as the approach I outlined does work.

Comment: i have two list
-custom list (venus)

Comment: i answered your question

Answer (score 0):

```
 String fileName = Path.GetFileName(_web.Site.RootWeb.Url + FileUrl);
 byte[] fileStream = _web.GetFile(lblUrl.Text).OpenBinary();// File.OpenRead(_web.Site.RootWeb.Url + lblUrl.Text);
 byte[] content = new byte[fileStream.Length];
 SPFolder myLibrary = _web.Folders[DocumentLib];
 myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, content, true);
 myLibrary.Update();
 SPFile file = _web.GetFile(myLibrary.Url + "/" + fileName);
 int itemid = file.Item.ID;
 SPListItem splistItem = destinatioList.GetItemById(itemid);
 splistItem["Field1"] = Field1;
 splistItem["Field2"] = Field2;
 splistItem["Field3"] = Field3;
 splistItem.Update();
```